# Allocating Memory to a String in a Struct

Tags: c, object, memory

Working on a fairly basic problem right now, cant quite seem to get my head around why I'm seg faulting! Still fairly new to C programming/allocating memory so sorry if this seems super simple.

I believe I'm assigning memory wrong, I'm just not sure how. Any help is awesome!

The function emalloc is just a malloc function in a different file with a null check:

```
void *emalloc(size_t s) {
void *result = malloc(s);
if(NULL == result) {
fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation Failure!");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}   
return result;
}


struct htablerec {
int capacity;
int num_keys;
char **keys;
int *frequency;

};

htable htable_new(int capacity){
int i;

htable htab = emalloc(sizeof *htab);
htab->capacity = capacity;
htab->num_keys = 0;
htab->frequency = emalloc(capacity * sizeof htab->frequency[0]);

for(i=0; i<capacity; i++){
    htab->keys[i] = emalloc((WORD_LEN + 1) * sizeof (char));
}

for(i=0;i< capacity;i++){
    htab->frequency[i]= 0;
    htab->keys[i] = NULL;

}
return htab;
}
```

Comment: From the incomplete fragment it looks as though you didn't allocate any memory to `htab->keys` before iterating `htab->keys[i]`

Comment: Is this PHP by any chance - emalloc?

Comment: What is `emalloc`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz emalloc is malloc which never returns NULL, because it gives a fatal error instead.

Comment: Note that `emalloc(0)` may errantly exit code.   `if(NULL == result && s > 0) {` would be better.

Comment: Note, good use of `sizeof htab->frequency[0]` in `htab->frequency = emalloc(capacity * sizeof htab->frequency[0]);`: using the size of the de-referenced type.  It would have been consistent to continue that with `htab->keys[i] = emalloc((WORD_LEN + 1) * sizeof htab->keys[i][0]);` as well with the missing `htab->keys = malloc(sizeof htab->keys[0] * capacity);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the structure, you are declaring an array of pointers to char.

```
char **keys;
```

First, you have to allocate enough space for these pointers before you assign memory to every-one of them.

```
htab->keys = malloc(sizeof(char*) * capacity);
```

You were accessing uninitialized pointer and it caused undefined behavior.

Comment: emalloc is just a malloc function in a different file with a null check :) sorry for confusion!

Comment: @Harry please [edit] your question and make that clear __there__.